# NuxtJS - Why is my vuex store state is always empty in middleware when access using SSR (Server side rendering)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store, nuxtjs

So i have this middleware files

middleware/authenticated.js

```
export default function (context) {
    //console.log('context.store.state :>> ', context.store.state);

    if(process.server === true) { //Server Side

        //why is my store state here is always empty when access in SSR
        console.log(context.store.state.authen.UserToken);

    } else { //Client Side

        if(!context.store.state.authen.UserToken) {
            context.redirect('/error');
        } else {
            //Refresh Token
            context.$axios.get("authen/refresh")
                .then((res) => {
                    const payload = {
                        UserToken: res.data.DataReturn.Token,
                        UserId: res.data.DataReturn.UserId,
                        UserEmail: res.data.DataReturn.UserEmail,
                        UserFullname: res.data.DataReturn.UserFullname
                    };
                    context.store.dispatch("authen/SetLogin", payload);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    context.redirect('/error');
                });
        }

    }
}
```

why it is my state is always empty when accessing in SSR, i can access the store if the call is from client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are expecting is a response on server. But the work is being done on the client side.
To your question `nuxtServerInit` is the answer. As SSR fires on the server side. So when you fetch your api, you need to fill the store with by calling `nuxtServerInit` like below.

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user) {
      commit('user', req.session.user)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ohh.. okay will try that. Thanks @power-cut